# Error: 'ros::TimeNotInitializedException' thrown due to calling ros::Time::now() before creating the first NodeHandle or calling ros::start()

Tags: roscpp, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried googling for an answer but it seems like the answers are targeted for rospy and not roscpp. Also, I am using ros indigo.

The code I am trying to run is pretty simple:

```
#include "generate_global_map.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_generate_global_map");

  std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;

  ros::Rate loop_rate(5); //10hz loop rate

  while (ros::ok()){

  ros::spinOnce(); //ros spin is to ensure that ros threading does not leave subscribes un processed
  loop_rate.sleep();

  }

  return 0;

}
```

When I try to rosrun this I get this error:

```
hello world
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::TimeNotInitializedException'
  what():  Cannot use ros::Time::now() before the first NodeHandle has been created or ros::start() has been called.      If this is a standalone app or test that just uses ros::Time and does not communicate over ROS, you may also call     ros::Time::init()
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Anyone know what the issue is?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210252/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-%27ros::timenotinitializedexception%27.-what():--cannot-use-ros::time::now()-before-the-first-nodehandle-has-been-created-or-ros::start()-has-been-called./) by [justiliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/22606/justiliang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-05-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Cannot use ros::Time::now() before the first NodeHandle has been created or ros::start() has been called.      If this is a standalone app or test that just uses ros::Time and does not communicate over ROS, you may also call     ros::Time::init()

I hate it when I get these kind of answers, but in this case I think the exception is actually pretty verbose and points you to your issue: you need to create a `ros::NodeHandle` instance before using any of `ros::Rate`, `ros::ok()` or `ros::spinOnce()`, or manually call `ros::start()` (but I doubt that is a recommended use of that API).

If you do not want a `NodeHandle`, you could (as the message tells you) also directly call `ros::Time::init()`.

See also the [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Additional info for this issue when using Cpp since this is the top result on google:

When you are facing this issue using classes with a ros::NodeHandle and ros::Rate, make sure the order is:

```
class A
{
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Rate r;
.
.
.
}
```

Otherwise the ros::Rate object will be created first which ends up with the same exception thrown.

---

Originally posted by [marcomasa](https://answers.ros.org/users/45483/marcomasa/) with karma: 11 on 2019-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1